# How to return result of EXEC and total number of rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that filters on multiple parameters. I would like to return the total number of rows from that query, but I also want to return just n-number of rows from the query result.

The query body looks something like this:

```
SET @SqlBody = 'select * from Customer c join Address a on c.Id = a.CustomerId 
where a.County = @countyParam 
order by c.Id Offset @rowOffsetParam rows 
fetch next @rowFetchParam rows only'
EXEC(@SqlBody)

@countyParam = 'Texas'
@rowOffsetParam = 0
@rowFetchParam = 20
```

What I want is I want to know how many Customer in total that are from a county Texas only, but I also want to return 20 rows only even if there are 2578 Customer that are from Texas.

Comment: With [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you could use a second query to retrieve the `count` and return it in an `output` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>SET @SqlBody = 'IF OBJECT_ID (N''#temptable'', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE select *,(select Count(*) from Customer c join Address a on c.Id = a.CustomerId 
where a.County = @countyParam) as Cnt 
into #TEMPTABLE from Customer c join Address a on c.Id = a.CustomerId 
where a.County = @countyParam 
order by c.Id 
SELECT Top 20 * FROM #TEMPTABLE'
EXEC(@SqlBody)</code>
```